# Translate Node Metatags using modules: il8n + metatags

Tags: i18n-l10n, meta-tags

How does one configure translation of Node metatags (Title, Description) which allows the content author to translate metatags from the node edit page?  Similar to how they translate individual fields from node edit page.

Using the [il8n module](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n), and URL method of translation:

> -Base Language: root/webpage
>   -Spanish: root/es/webpage

Thank You!